# Threading causing blocking; Not present when synchronous

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I am stumped.  I have a bit of code that goes out and searches my database.  It does 7 different searches at the same time.

To get them to run at the same time I use threading.  I have tried several different ways to call it, but right now I am using something like this:

```
var encounterResults = new List<IODataList<ISearchResultItem>>();

Parallel.ForEach(functions, function =>
{
    var results = function(searchParam, ClientId);
    encounterResults.Add(results);
});
```

It all works very well when run by itself.

However, when my user clicks my Save Button, I call a WCF service operation asynchronously.  While that service operation is being called, if the user fires of a search (using the above code), the search waits until the WCF Service operation completes, then the search completes.

I cannot see anything that the search cares about that the save button also cares about.  (They don't share any objects.)

Just for fun, I tried changing my search to look like this

```
foreach (var function in functions)
{
    var results = function(searchParam, ClientId);
    encounterResults.Add(results);
}
```

When I run it like that (synchronously) it has no problems with the save button.  (The search is not blocked.)

But some of my searches can take a while, so I worry about just going synchronous.

I have tried all I can think of to see what could be causing this block, but I am stumpped.  I am wondering if it is something related to threading itself.  (For example I thought I might be out of threads, but ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads shows I am only using a few.)

Anyone know what could be causing my threads to block?

**UPDATE:**

I tried having only one `function` in my collection of `functions` and the blocking did not occur when run though the threaded method.  However if I add just one more it blocks.  So something about two or more together causes this.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration in the loop writes to the same shared `List<T>`.

Try adding locks around the writing to the list in your parallel version and see if the hangs go away.